# C# Expression.PropertyOrField in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to get expressions for the first level properties of a given class, through an array of strings, each one related to the property name to get the expression:

```
public List<MemberExpression> CreateMembers(string propertyPaths)
{
    List<MemberExpression> test = new List<MemberExpression>();



    var propertiesPath = propertyPaths.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var propertyPath in propertiesPath)
    {
        var mainParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Process), "e");
        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(mainParameter, typeof(Process), propertyPath);
        test.Add(property);
        property = null;
        mainParameter = null;
    }

    return test;
}
```

I'm trying to get the public virtual properties from this class:

```
public class Process

{

     public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

     public int? RecommendationId { get; set; }

     public int? DiagnosisNodeId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("DiagnosisId")]
     public virtual Diagnosis Diagnosis { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("DiagnosisNodeId")]
     public virtual DiagnosisNode DiagnosisNode { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("RecommendationId")]
     public virtual Recommendation Recommendation { get; set; }
}
```

but after the first iteration the Expression.Property always throws an exception that the given property doesn't exist in the class Process.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You aren't actually using `.PropertyOrField` in the code - I assume you mean the line that uses `.Property` ? do you have an example of the input you're using? what is the value of `propertyPaths` here?

Comment: this worked just fine for me (where `P` is just what I called the outer type): `var members = new P().CreateMembers("CompanyId,RecommendationId");` and `foreach(var member in members) { Console.WriteLine(member); }` - do you have an example that fails?

Comment: unrelated note: you don't need a different parameter per loop iteration - they can all use the same parameter instance (`mainParameter`) quite happily

Comment: you're right, I edited the code to match the question title.

Comment: an example of the propertyPaths is: `"Diagnosis, DiagnosisNode"`

Comment: the P() should be the Process() in my code right?

Comment: "the P() should be the Process() in my code right?" - no; in my test rig, `P` is the thing that has `CreateMembers`.

Comment: the `CreateMembers` is like the constructor of the `P`? My problem was that I didn't applied the Trim, so it was trying to process the name of the property with an empty space in the beginning. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> an example of the propertyPaths is: `"Diagnosis, DiagnosisNode"`

The problem is the space after the comma. There is no property called `" DiagnosisNode"` (with a leading space). Either use `.Trim()` on the strings coming back from `Split`, or don't include the space in the first place.

Comment: this solved the problem, thank you so much, I really didn't notice the missing of the `Trim()`.